# jQuery doesn't run the first time, but everytime after

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

The author and caption do not display on first click, but every event after.  Need help fast and greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/zach57/6B2s9/1/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="gallery-stacked">
      <li class="gallery-thumb"><a title="Image 1" data-caption="This is a caption" data-author="Mr. Cupcake" href="#"><img class="gth img-responsive center-block" src="//placehold.it/600x350"></a></li>
      <li class="gallery-thumb"><a title="Image 2" data-caption="This is a caption" data-author="Mr. Cupcake" href="#"><img class="gth img-responsive center-block" src="//placehold.it/600x350/2255EE"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="modalCarousel" class="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner"> </div>
            <p class="modal-caption"></p>
            <p class="modal-author"></p>
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a> <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('li .gth').on('load', function() {

}).each(function(i) {
  if(this.complete) {
    var item = $('<div class="item"></div>');
    var itemli = $(this).parents('li');
    var title = $(this).parent('a').attr("title");
    var caption = $(this).parent('a').attr("data-caption");
    var author = $(this).parent('a').attr("data-author");   

    item.attr("title",title);
    item.attr("data-caption",caption);
    item.attr("data-author",author);

    $(itemli.html()).appendTo(item);
    item.appendTo('.carousel-inner'); 
    if (i==0){ // set first item active
    item.addClass('active');
    }
  }
});

/* activate the carousel */
$('#modalCarousel').carousel({interval:false});

/* change modal title when slide changes */
$('#modalCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  $('.modal-title').html($(this).find('.active').attr("title"));
  $('.modal-caption').html($(this).find('.active').attr("data-caption")).addClass('text-center');
  $('.modal-author').html($(this).find('.active').attr("data-author")).addClass('text-right');
})

/* when clicking a thumbnail */
$('li .gth').click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).parents('li').index();
    var id = parseInt(idx);
    $('#myModal').modal('show'); // show the modal
    $('#modalCarousel').carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected

});
```

I'm sure its my jQuery but I'm not an expert.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that `.on('load',function() {})` piece? Also, when/where in your page are you trying to load your JS?

Comment: Is it not the same duplicate question that you asked 2 hour ago ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/21732910/2454790

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your problem is, but is this fixed? http://jsfiddle.net/6B2s9/3/ I just included jQuery, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: It is the same question, but I didn't tag it the best way possible.  I'm new, clearly.  The problem when, everything runs great except, it if you click the first image once the page loads, the caption and author do not appear.  The problem is the first image, the first time the page is loaded; otherwise, it works just find.

Comment: The questions look very similar. @zach57 if you have more information on a question please edit the original question instead of submitting another one.

Comment: I have removed that question since this thread is getting a response.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  My problem was checking if i == 0.  Since the modal window can started on any picture, i can not be checked on what the value is.  So, i cannot evalutate, since i can be the first image or the 99th.

So here, is the jQuery solution.

```
$('li .gth').on('load', function() {

}).each(function(i) {
  if(this.complete) {
    var item = $('<div class="item"></div>');
    var itemli = $(this).parents('li');
    var title = $(this).parent('a').attr("title");
    var caption = $(this).parent('a').attr("data-caption");
    var author = $(this).parent('a').attr("data-author");   

    item.attr("title",title);
    item.attr("data-caption",caption);
    item.attr("data-author",author);

    $(itemli.html()).appendTo(item);
    item.appendTo('.carousel-inner'); 
    if (i){ // set i item active
    item.addClass('active');
    }
  }
});

/* activate the carousel */
$('#modalCarousel').carousel({interval:false});

/* change modal title when slide changes */
$('#modalCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  $('.modal-title').html($(this).find('.active').attr("title"));
  $('.modal-caption').html($(this).find('.active').attr("data-caption")).addClass('text-center');
  $('.modal-author').html($(this).find('.active').attr("data-author")).addClass('text-right');
})

/* when clicking a thumbnail */
$('li .gth').click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).parents('li').index();
    var id = parseInt(idx);
    $('#myModal').modal('show'); // show the modal
    $('#modalCarousel').carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected

});
```

I'm sure the code could be cleaned up, but it is at least working now.